# Question about acceleration & deceleration in real world?

Tags: acceleration, velocity, speed

have searched the net and am not satisfied with any answer I have found to calculate the following:- Here is an example just for reference.
Suppose I can accelerate my car from 0-100km/h in 10s. That means my acceleration=2.78m/s/s. Say at 7000Rpm it hits 100km/h in the first gear itself. Now, while I am still very much in gear I lift my leg off the accelerator (no clutch is pressed). It will begin to decelerate, till it hits 1000Rpm and keeps that constant rolling pace of 14km/h.
I want to find out the rate at which deceleration takes place? I want you to keep drag/aerodynamics/friction (air & road) etc etc as any normal accepted values, no preciseness required over there. Just need an approximate idea of how I could calculate the rate at which speed drops.

Comment: Why would you down vote a question without even a reason?

Comment: Just a note: if you accelerate to 100 km/h in 10 s, your acceleration would be more like 2.78 m/s/s, not 10 m/s/s.

Comment: Only a measurement is going to tell you this. Too many factors like braking on engine, air drag and rolling resistance that are poorly known to make a reasonable estimate, IMHO.

Comment: Sorry @Joshua you are right.. Over sight while trying to exhibit an easy example! ;-)

Comment: Yes Gert you are right, but still a car rolling in neutral slows down at a lesser rate than the same car/speed when made to decelerate with still being in gear without the accelerator being pressed. In both cases the forces you have mentioned exists and act upon the same car. But I'm looking at some sort of logic or way of calculating that engine Breaking while the car is still in gear, that makes it slow down faster than the one in neutral, get what i mean?

Comment: Another note: if $7000RPM => 100km/h$, then $1000RPM => 14km/h$, not $6km/h$. You might fix this and the mistake @Joshua noted in your question.

Comment: @user3833732 , does the car have an automatic transmission or a manual transmission?

Comment: Let's say Manual. But even if there is a logic for calculating the rate at which a car slows down while still in a particular gear ratio (for automatic), I would like to understand your view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to measure this by bringing your car to top speed, putting it into idle, and then watching the speed over time as the car decelerates. [Here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Measure-the-drag-coefficient-of-your-car/) are some simple instructions, which will yield your deceleration rate at any given speed. Then, choose at what speeds you'll shift and how long it will take, and you'll have your answers.

Comment: Yes! This is definitely the best answer for drag etc. Very comprehensive. But here is where my question differs. Please see the two senarios. 1)Reaching 100km/h and then rolling in neutral and 2)Reaching 100km/h and then no more accelerator but staying in gear. In 1) this deceleration is due to drag/friction etc etc. In 2) we will slow down faster, cause besides the above forces slowing us down like in 1, there is also some kinda engine breakage. So I'm looking for a logic to approximate/calculate that. Hope I'm getting through

Comment: Well, measuring this is really going to be the best way to find it out. There are way too many variables to just calculate it.

Comment: Could you measure the distance traveled in both scenarios? And then compare the two?

Comment: Haha, Zarko, that is exactly what I finally need, hence I'm first trying to get deceleration before I get displacement!